# Export HAR file using chrome QUIC protocol (HTTPS)

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, har

I am trying to export HAR file using Chrome and QUIC through python.
QUIC protocol using TLS1.3 - so i can only use the protocol with the client certificate

- I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075645/export-har-using-chromedriver) answer (use a proxy server) but the proxy doesn't have the client certificate to enable QUIC so all the HAR files is HTTP1.1 protocol.
- I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3) code (use the chrome profile setting) but i can't export a HAR file using this one.

Basically, i want to merge this 2 codes into one.
Export a HAR file using chrome profile (to enable TLS1.3, HTTPS and QUIC)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

and

```py
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import json
import urlparse

server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
url = urlparse.urlparse (proxy.proxy).path
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(url))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options =chrome_options)
proxy.new_har("http://stackoverflow.com", options={'captureHeaders': True})
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")    
result = json.dumps(proxy.har, ensure_ascii=False)
print result
proxy.stop()    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to implement this scenario (capture a HAR file with the Chrome default profile) is using **chrome-har-capturer** command in Linux. Setup from the following link:

https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer

After installing this you can start chrome from the command line like this:

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

capturing HAR file using the command (saving the HAR file into the current path):

```
chrome-har-capturer -o <filename> <website>
```

You can write a short program in python using 'os' and 'subprocess' libraries:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import time

CHROME_TYPE = "google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222"
FILE_NAME = "example.har"
WEBSITE = " https://www.youtube.com"

def main():
    # open new terminal for 'open chrome' command
    browserProcess = subprocess.Popen(CHROME_TYPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    # wait for the chrome window opening
    time.sleep(3)
    # the action include only one line
    os.system("chrome-har-capturer -o "+FILE_NAME+WEBSITE)
    # optional:
    browserProcess.kill()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```